# Start the script in PyQt5 and python3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have two separate scripts, on the one hand I have the program created in python3 called **counting.py** and on the other hand I have created the GUI in PyQt5 called **interface.py** with the functionalities that I need.

My question is:

How can I do so that the moment I click on the "Start" button of the interface, connect with **counting.py** and start the created program?

```
  self.btnStart.clicked.connect(??)
```

Some kind of function that connects with **conteo.py**??

Thanks for any help or comment.

Comment: I think that this is not the same question, basically because I ask about PyQt5... but ok.. thank you dude.

Comment: Please eyllanesc could you help me with this issue? im not able to connect my interface start button with my counting.py thank you